# Wordpress not showing thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, image, wordpress-featured-image

I am using the Plugin Auto Featured Image to set thumbnails automatically. And in the database it shows updated meta thumbnail key.

[image: Wordpress Database meta keys]

But for some reason it is not showing the featured image. It doesn't show a "placeholder" neither. It just shows nothing at all.

Also, when I try to view the attachment on a single page, it does not show it.

How can I proceed to find the problem? If you need more screenshots of different tables on my database, please ask. I really appreciate your time.

**EDIT**

```
$meta_values = get_post_meta( $POST_ID, '_thumbnail_id');
error_log(var_dump($meta_values)) //Prints nothing on error log

//Note: $POST_ID is fine, it contains the right id. Problem not there.
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail($post_parent_id) ){
error_log("THUMB EXISTS". get_post_thumbnail_id($post_parent_id));
}
```

Really **weird** result:

THUMB EXISTS: "Blank space, No id or string at all"....

Comment: Please provide code you use to display it.

Comment: I'm not doing anything special. It's the default wordpress theme. Even if I change it to another wordpress theme, it still does not work.

Comment: @NielsvanRenselaar updated question with a little more info :)

Comment: Check $POST_ID has value

Comment: @VidyaNair thanks for taking your time. But as I wrote under the code that variable is set and it is numeric and it contains the post id.

Answer (score 0):

1) get post thumbnail with post id [full description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
```

2) In a loop [full description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
```

3 want to get the thumb url ?? . Use this

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" longdesc="URL_2" alt="Text_2" />
```